# How to name files after values of a variable in a dataset?

Tags: bash, loops, file, while-loop, mkdir

I have a list file containing 4 columns. (each column contains +100 lines)

For each line, I have to create a directory containing the value of column3 and place them in a directory containing the value of column4.
AND
For each line I should place the value of column2 into a file named after column1. Those files should be placed in the directory of column3.

I created a while loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
  
 file1=$column3
 file2=$column4 
  
 while read line
    do
      mkdir $column3 
      mkdir $column3/$column4 
      echo -e "$line"                                                                                                                                             
 
    done <list.csv
```

but that doesn't work ... Any idea ?

Comment: would be nice to have a example for input what the output should look like

Comment: please remove the line numbers [Why is there no line numbering in code sections?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252559/995714)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to say more about what isn't working.  Do you see an error message?  If so, what is it?  It is not producing the expected output?  If not, what output do you see and what output do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a whitespace delimiter, and the spec

> For each line, I have to create a directory containing the value of column3 and place them in a directory containing the value of column4. AND For each line I should place the value of column2 into a file named after column1. Those files should be placed in the directory of column3.

`create a directory containing the value of column3` is unclearly worded, but if it means *"create a directory named with the value of column 3"*, and the same for column 4, then,

```
while read -r one two three four; do
    mkdir -p "$four/$three"
    echo "$two" > "$four/$three/$one"
done < list.csv
```

Read your order of operands carefully.
`mkdir -p` allows multiple levels to be created at once, and doesn't crash if they already exist.

You could also use an array, but you need to adjust your offsets for base 0, so it's less clear to match the code against the directions.

```
while read -r -a col; do
    mkdir -p "${col[3]}/${col[2]}"
    echo "${col[1]}" > "${col[3]}/${col[2]}/${col[0]}"
done < list.csv
```

If you have a different delimiter, set IFS. For example, if your delimiter is a comma, use

```
while IFS=, read -r one two three four
```

instead of just

```
while read -r one two three four
```

If your file is more on the format of

```
"a", "b", "c", "d"
```

then you should probably be using `awk`, but for the sake of completeness in `bash`, you could use something like -

```
while IFS=, read -r one two three four; do
    mkdir -p "$four/$three"
    echo "$two" > "$four/$three/$one"
done < <( sed 's/^ *"//; s/" *$//; s/", *"/,/g' list.csv )
```

assuming there are no commas *embedded* in any fields.